# URL encoding in PHP

Tags: php, html, get, urlencode, urldecode

I am trying to see if URL encoding of [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) parameters while submitting a form is possible. I have seen a few resources where URL encoding is being is used where the URLs are built dynamically

```
Example: www.google.com?query=urlencode($query)
```

But how do I apply the function [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) if I am using a form and a submit button?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="send.php" method="get">
            <input type="input" name="method" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *if i don't misunderstood your question*, why you don't use urlencode() ?

Comment: In your comments below you never test with characters that actually get encoded, e.g. spaces. Try it. "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is the default encoding. You can't expect an encoding of the whole query part (starting with "?"), just the individual parts values. And note there are subtle (historical) differencies between urlencode and rawurlencode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will urlencode them for you.  Go to google and search for "&", and you'll see "q=%26" in the URL.

Comment: hey but I still am able to see what I have passed as parameters. Nothing has changed. localhost/test.php?opt1=check_test&subt=subt, is what I get when I submit

Answer (score 2):

This is done by the browser if you ask it to do it. Consider using enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded":

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="send.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="input" name="method" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that it is done by default in most modern browsers if you don't even specify *enctype*.

Comment: hey but I still am able to see what I have passed as parameters. Nothing has changed. localhost/test.php?opt1=check_test&subt=subt, is what I get when I submit

Comment: Of course you wont see that for what you have entered, you will see for special characters like &, #, / and so on, the other characters are not changed at all